# Spring SecurityContext being cleared after page load

Tags: spring, spring-security, zk

I am integrating ZK with Spring Security, so far I've configured the latter so all URLs are secured except for the login page. Which of course works fine when page switching takes place by navigating to different URLs.

However, when I change some content dynamically (i.e. by changing the src attribute of an `Include` element in ZK), and then within the controller of that new content I call SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(), I obtain no sort of credentials, but a null as the `Authentication` object. My guess is that the culprit is pointed by this line in debug:

```
SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

The problem is I obtain all my data from a REST webservice that uses Basic Authentication, so I need to obtain the user's credentials on every request, and that includes those of dynamically loaded content.

I've seen I could set my SecurityContext level to be global, but I've also read it is bad practice and it could cause users to obtain someone else's credentials.

PS: Funny thing is, if instead of:

```
  Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

I use:

```
Authentication authentication = ((org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl)session().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT")).getAuthentication();
```

My Authentication object is in fact there. So there must be something I'm missing here.

EDIT: here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>XESAC</display-name>


    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <!-- A servlet filter capturing every user requests and sending them to 
        the configured security filters to make sure access is authorized. -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>sigur-ui.root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/spring/appcontext-spring.xml,classpath:/spring/appcontext-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <description>Spring Loader</description>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <description>Used to cleanup when a session is destroyed</description>
        <display-name>ZK Session Cleaner</display-name>
        <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>



    <servlet>
        <description>
            The ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
            <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dspLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.web.servlet.dsp.InterpreterServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>class-resource</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dspLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.dsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.zul</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error.zul</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

appcontext-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:zksp="http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="disabled"/>

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/zkau/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <!-- En funcion del rol de cada usuario -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.zul" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/timeout.zul" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <!-- Areas Patterns -->
        <form-login login-page="/login.zul" authentication-failure-url="/login.zul?login_error=1" default-target-url="/index.zul" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login.zul" logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true" />
    </http>

    <!-- Autenticación mock para las pruebas -->
    <authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
        <authentication-provider ref="myProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="myProvider" class="com.myapp.provider.MyProvider" />

</beans:beans>
```

MyProvider.java (this is a class of my own that authenticates against a REST endpoint):

```
public class MyProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private IAuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @Autowired
    private HttpSession session;



    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        UserDetailsDTO userDetails = authenticationService.doAuthenticate(authentication);
        if (null != userDetails && !userDetails.isAnonymous()) {
            session.setAttribute("user", userDetails);
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            //should set the roles here
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, grantedAuths);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not know much of ZK, but what does this line mean in your `appcontext-security.xm` `<http pattern="/zkau/**" security="none" />` ? If ZK uses those URL, they are not processed by spring security and authentication will by null.

Comment: I put that pattern to require authentication; this somehow made it work, that part of the code I copied from elsewhere, can you tell me what is that URL pattern for?

Comment: sadly this broke my login page, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your security config, you have that line :

```
<http pattern="/zkau/**" security="none" />
```

All URLs beginning with `/zkau` completely by-pass the spring security filter. If ZK uses those URLs which are not processed by spring security, the `Authentication` will be null.

You should at least remove that line from `appcontext-security.xml`

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is absolutely correct. First of all, REST requires to be stateless, so every request must be negotiated. If you want that to be persistent for the human interface, you must do:

```
<beans:bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter" />
```

but say

```
<security:http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="stateless" />
```

Comment: There's two tiers involved here, the REST tier and the UI tier. My problem comes whithin the UI tier, in which there is a user session (since its a web application). I am not keeping state on my REST endpoint, which is why I need to obtain the user & password for every request I make and put them in an Authentication header (I am using Basic Authentication)

Comment: That is clear. What did you try to say with your statement? Try the snippet above. If you REST is a browser which calls UI, it is fine to persist that otherwise not recommended. More over, I would empty two endpoints for the REST service. One for browsers, one for real REST clients. It should solve your problem.

Comment: But I don't think I understand your answer, where are you suggesting I put those lines? Can you expand on your answer explaingin the reasoning? The problem I have is, between different calls to the REST endpoint from the UI, I lose the SecurityContext (on the UI tier). I am fine on the REST tier (or at least I think I am, if I'm not please correct me), I capture every request, then through basic authentication obtain user infor for each request that is made, and it's working.

Comment: Who is performing the REST calls? Does the server respond witha JSESSIONID and does the client provide that back?

Comment: No; the UI tier is making those calls. To the user, it's transparent whether the calls are made to a REST endpoint or not. And no, I'm not using any sessionId info, since my REST is stateless I shouldn't rely on this, should I? The process is as follows: User loads a page that requires data access (data is dependant on the user), a REST request is done with Authorization header plus user+password; REST (set to Basic Auth) service receives request, checks those credentials against the database, and allows access to the requested method (Im using @PreAuthorize annotations on the REST tier).

Comment: UI is a browser or custom software?

Comment: It's a web application, so it's in the browser but the request is performed on the server side.

Comment: How can the request be perfomed on the server side? The client has to issue a HTTP request. Are you re-executing those requests internally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59096/discussion-between-kelmer-and-michael-o).